# how to change the color of a String class

Tags: ruby

I created a method to modify the colors of the String class, but I can not. The following code:

```
class String
  @colors_hash = { red: 31, green: 32, yellow: 33, blue: 34, pink: 35, light_blue: 94, white: 97, light_grey: 37, black: 30 }

  def self.create_colors
    @colors_hash.each do |key, value|
      self.class_eval("def #{key}; '\e[#{value}m #{self} \e[0m'; end")
    end
  end

end
```

When I do, "Gleydson".red

it returns "String" in red color and not "Gleydson" in red

Comment: I think you should mention that you call `String.create_colors` before running `"Gleydson".red`

Comment: Creating a class-level instance variable is extremely messy. As your definitions are created once, this would be better represented as a constant, though if it's never used again you can just iterate over it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty bad practice in general but:

```
String.class_eval do

  { red: 31, green: 32, yellow: 33, blue: 34, pink: 35, light_blue: 94, white: 97, light_grey: 37, black: 30 }.each do |color,value|
    define_method(color) do
      "\e[#{value}m #{self} \e[0m"
    end
  end

end

puts "Ruby".red
```

Answer (score 2):

Please never tell anybody I helped you with this.

```
class String
  @colors_hash = { red: 31, green: 32, yellow: 33, blue: 34,
                   pink: 35, light_blue: 94, white: 97,
                   light_grey: 37, black: 30 }

  def self.create_colors
    @colors_hash.each do |key, value|
      #                                            ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ problem
      # self.class_eval("def #{key}; '\e[#{value}m #{self} \e[0m'; end")
      define_method key do
        "\e[#{value}m #{self} \e[0m"
      end
    end
  end    
end
```

The problem with your code was that `#{self}` was interpolated *during* interpolation of an argument to a call to `class_eval`, and `self` there is `String` constant.

Comment: This preserves the original, quirky behaviour where words get spaced out. Not sure why those spaces are in the string as that seems to be a mistake.

Comment: @tadman me neither, but I am to show what’s caused the error and how to fix it, not how to improve the code in general. The latter in this case requires [4 hours of coding](https://github.com/am-kantox/logrithm/blob/master/lib/logrithm/utils/color.rb)  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to add a bunch of methods to a core class you might want to define a context for them so it's obvious where they came from:

```
module ColorExtensions
  {
    red: 31,
    green: 32,
    yellow: 33,
    blue: 34,
    pink: 35,
    light_blue: 94,
    white: 97,
    light_grey: 37,
    black: 30
  }.each do |color, code|
    define_method color do
      "\e[#{code}m#{self}\e[0m"
    end
  end
end

String.include(ColorExtensions)

puts "test".red.inspect
```

This has the advantage of working on other objects, anything that supports `to_s`.

Comment: The best answer here so far. I wonder why another one was selected as “correct.”

Answer (score 0):

Rather than defining a method for each colour, you could use [BasicObject#method_missing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing).

```
class String
  COLORS_HASH = { red: 31, green: 32, yellow: 33, blue: 34, pink: 35,
                  light_blue: 94, white: 97, light_grey: 37, black: 30 }

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)        
    return "\e[#{COLORS_HASH[name]}m #{self} \e[0m" if COLORS_HASH.key?(name)
    super
  end
end

puts "Gleydson".red
Gleydson (in red) 

puts "Gleydson".green
Gleydson (in green) 

puts "Gleydson".khaki
  #=>NoMethodError: undefined method `khaki' for "Gleydson":String
```